# Generate HTML background from sprite

Tags: php, html, image, css-sprites

I have a sprite sheet that I want to create a background from, but I want to generate it randomly from separate parts of the sheet. I'd rather not generate a full-sized image each time, as I don't want to have to store one for each session, can anyone help me?

I'm hoping it can be done with PHP but I'm not set on it. Any clues much appreciated.

Comment: Why would you need to do this?

Comment: For a bit of a laugh...? Not a good enough reason?

Comment: Are you talking about using `background-repeat`?

Comment: No, that's largely the point. I don't want to repeat it, I want to generate each segment randomly.

Comment: is there any implementation of this on some site already. I don't exactly know what you mean yet.

Comment: Not as far as I can tell actually. I was looking for anything similar but can't find any. Umm, I want to randomly designate each square of the background one at a time, from a different sprite. I'm thinking along the lines of temporary files. I think it's going to need more thinking about though.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10031/discussion-between-rpm-and-rob-maths-rob-lee)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is getting "parts" of the sprite image and layering them.  For this reason alone I'd be tempted not even consider CSS background images and go with layering everything on top of a htm5 canvas or svg or something.  I guess you could separate the sprites beforehand, generate data uri variants (Mime encoded) and include it into your stylesheet that way (then the matter actually becomes trivial for modern browsers,as you can layer as many background images as you wish, all through CSS... well, except for the random positioning bit.  That you'd have to do through either php or javascript.